# Why am I not able to see the up arrow in my action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to navigate to my previous activity. I want to use up arrow of action bar  (Toolbar).I am not able to see the up arrow in my action bar(Toolbar). I am attaching the activity code below.

ImageActivity.java

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    int img,img1;
    String text;
    ImageView imgicon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        imgicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

        Bundle bundle =  getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle!=null)
        {
        img = bundle.getInt("img");
        text = bundle.getString("Phone");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("text");
        imgicon.setImageResource(img);
        }

        img1 = bundle.getInt("img1");
        imgicon.setImageResource(img1);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //Write your logic here
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever faced this situation and somehow found a way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try using this

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        try {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionbar != null) {
                actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
```

and use this in XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it is not working ...Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Srikanth86in it will work absolutely fine but please check your accent color and primary color also sometimes it goes enable but have merged in background   color

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```